# Using CASE function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like:

```
2   Savita  EC1 50
2   Savita  EC2 55
2   Savita  EC3 28
2   Savita  EC4 30
2   Savita  EC5 60
3   Abhi    EC1 40
3   Abhi    EC2 38
3   Abhi    EC3 35
3   Abhi    EC4 45
3   Abhi    EC5 37
4   Priya   EC1 60
4   Priya   EC2 49
4   Priya   EC3 26
4   Priya   EC4 29
4   Priya   EC5 44
5   Shanthi EC1 70
5   Shanthi EC2 19
5   Shanthi EC3 45
5   Shanthi EC4 44
5   Shanthi EC5 50
6   Harish  EC1 60
6   Harish  EC2 64
6   Harish  EC3 26
6   Harish  EC4 28
6   Harish  EC5 29
```

I want to add grace marks and the condition is
total grace marks per student is max of 6 marks, if the candidate has failed in two subs like 28 in EC1 and 27 in EC2, then after adding grace EC1=30 and EC2=30. and he is pass. if he has 25 marks in EC1 and 28 marks in EC2 , then  grace mark needed is 5+2=7 . hence he is fail and no grace marks added, Grace marks can be added to max two subjects. if he failed in more than 2 subjects then he is failed no grace marks added.
I have a proc Like

```
create procedure SP_student3
as
begin
select FstudentName,EC1,EC2,EC3,EC4,EC5,TOTALMARKS, CASE 
WHEN EC1<30 THEN 'FAIL'
WHEN EC2<30 THEN 'FAIL'
WHEN EC3<30 THEN 'FAIL'
WHEN EC4<30 THEN 'FAIL'
WHEN EC5<30 THEN 'FAIL'
ELSE 'PASS' END AS RESULT FROM(select FstudentName,EC1,EC2,EC3,EC4,EC5,TOTALMARKS=EC1+EC2+EC3+EC4+EC5 FROM Student   PIVOT(SUM(FMarks) for Fsubject in ([EC1],[EC2],[EC3],[EC4],[EC5],TOTALMARKS]))ASPIVOTTABLE )B end
```

Which gives out put as

```
Abhi    40  38  35  45  37  195 PASS
Harish  60  64  26  28  29  207 FAIL
Priya   60  49  26  29  44  208 FAIL
Savita  50  55  28  30  60  223 FAIL
Shanthi 70  19  45  44  50  228 FAIL
```

Comment: This question is very unclear. I suggest getting a colleague or friend to help you with the English part of it.

Comment: And you're showing EC1 through EC5 as *values* in your data, but you're using them like *columns* in your code.

Comment: So your 6 "marks" means that the person can be total 6 points under the target in any number of exams and that is still a success?

Comment: If the person is under 30 in any subject after adding grace marks then that person is fail.We can give grace marks max of 6 marks to only 2 subjects which are below 30. 6 marks is the maximum amount of marks we can give to a person.

Comment: Based on google results, "grace mark" seems to be a term used mainly in India, so that's why the question is not clear for anybody else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my assumptions are correct, you're looking for this:

```
SELECT A.StudentName, EC1,EC2,EC3,EC4,EC5,Total,
  case when failures > 6 or subjects > 2 then 'Failure'
       else 'Pass' end as Result
FROM
(  SELECT StudentName, EC1, EC2, EC3, EC4, EC5
      FROM Student
      PIVOT(sum(Marks) for subject in([EC1],[EC2],[EC3],[EC4],[EC5]))as pt) A,
(  select
      studentName,
      sum(case when Marks <  30 then 30 - Marks else 0 end) as failures,
      sum(case when Marks <  30 then 1 else 0 end) as subjects,
      sum(marks) as total
  from
      student
  group by
      studentname
) B
where 
    A.StudentName = B.StudentName
```

Which is pretty close to the answer in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30815516/4420967)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0755a4/2)

Edit: Added the check for 2 subjects, although the test data does not contain any cases like that.

Comment: Thank you, But i want to add grace marks to those subjects(which are less than 30) of that person who is pass after adding grace marks.

Comment: @LagnajitPuhan What do you mean by adding? That adds the grace marks and reports as fail if it is not enough

Comment: @LagnajitPuhan You want just to show all those numbers as "30"?

Comment: Not all those who have passed after adding grace marks.

Comment: @LagnajitPuhan Then you have to add rule to every column like this "case when [EC1] < 30 and failures <= 6 and subjects <= 2 then 30 else [EC1] end as [EC1]"

Answer (score 1):

I took a slightly different approach to this problem. If you add two columns to your table - "GraceMarks" (int) and Pass (bit), you can do this with a number of sequential and logical update queries and a simple select in the end. I had this in a table called "test", but you can change this of course to "student".

```
-- Find if students passed or failed the year

-- Assume students are all intitally flagged to Pass, and gracemarks are zero.
 update test SET Pass=1, GraceMarks=0

-- First, any mark <=23 is a fail
update test SET Pass=0 where Mark<=23 

-- if a student failed one subject, they fail them all
update test SET Pass=0 where StudentID in (
    SELECT      StudentID 
    from        dbo.test 
    where       Pass=0)

-- Next work out how many grace marks would be needed to pass each subject
update test SET GraceMarks=30-Mark where Mark<30 and Pass=1

-- If a student used more that a total of 6 grace marks, they failed too
update test SET Pass=0 where StudentID in (
    SELECT     StudentID 
    FROM         dbo.Test
    GROUP BY StudentID
    HAVING      (SUM(GraceMarks) > 6))

-- If they used grace marks in 3 or more subjects ... fail
update test SET Pass=0 where StudentID in (
    SELECT     StudentID
    FROM         dbo.Test
    WHERE     (GraceMarks > 0)
    GROUP BY StudentID
    HAVING      (COUNT(GraceMarks) > 2))    

-- Now show results
select      StudentID, StudentName,
            sum(case course when 'EC1' then mark end) as EC1,
            sum(case course when 'EC2' then mark end) as EC2,
            sum(case course when 'EC3' then mark end) as EC3,
            sum(case course when 'EC4' then mark end) as EC4,
            sum(case course when 'EC5' then mark end) as EC5,
            SUM(mark) as totalMark,
            CASE Pass WHEN 0 THEN 'Fail' ELSE 'Pass' END AS YearPassorFail

from        dbo.Test 
group by    StudentID, StudentName, CASE Pass WHEN 0 THEN 'Fail' ELSE 'Pass' END
order by        StudentName
```

The output of this code is this table --

```
3   Abhi    40  38  35  45  37  195 Pass 
6   Harish  60  64  26  28  29  207 Fail
4   Priya   60  49  26  29  44  208 Pass
2   Savita  50  55  28  30  60  223 Pass
5   Shanthi 70  19  45  44  50  228 Fail
```

You could add an additional column called "reason" and change the queries above to include the reason why they failed (Harish because 3 subjects <30 or needing 7 grace marks, Shanthi because one subject below 24).

The advantage of this approach is that you can see what is happening at each step, and you have a record of the Pass/Fail and grace marks used. You could then write queries finding out things like - how many grace marks were used? Who would have failed if the grace marks were only allowed at 3? etc. I also personally like lots of simple steps than one huge complex one, but that might just be me.